# Child window not showing up in x11

Tags: c++, linux, window, x11

I have created two windows. One with 32 bit and the other with 24 bits. The 32 bit window renders opengl and creates graphics with an alpha component onto it. The 24 bit window renders video. Both of the windows are child of a main window which is 32 bits. To my knowledge, when I call `XRestackWindows`, it show stack the windows such that the 32 bit window is on the top while also showing the 24 bit window underneath. This is not the case. When I do so, it only shows the 32 bit window. I know the 24 bit window is there because if I switch the order, then I only get to see the 24 bit window. Why is this the case?

```
/* Open the standard display (the primary screen) */
x_display = XOpenDisplay ( NULL );

visual_template.screen = DefaultScreen(x_display);
visual_list = XGetVisualInfo(x_display, VisualScreenMask, &visual_template, &nxvisuals);

XMatchVisualInfo(x_display, XDefaultScreen(x_display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo))

parent = XDefaultRootWindow(x_display);
XSync(x_display, True);
visual = vinfo.visual;
depth = vinfo.depth;

XSetWindowAttributes  swa;
swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | PointerMotionMask | KeyPressMask;
swa.colormap = XCreateColormap(x_display, XDefaultRootWindow(x_display), visual, AllocNone);
swa.background_pixel = 0;
swa.border_pixel = 0;

main_window = XCreateWindow (
          x_display, parent,
          0, 0, m_plane_width, m_plane_height, 0,
          depth, InputOutput,
          visual, CWEventMask | CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel,
          &swa );

/* Create a window */
opengl_window = XCreateWindow (
          x_display, main_window,
          0, 0, m_plane_width, m_plane_height, 0,
          depth, InputOutput,
          visual, CWEventMask | CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel,
          &swa );


int cnxvisuals = 0;
XVisualInfo cvisual_template;
XVisualInfo *cvisual_list;
XVisualInfo cvinfo;
Visual *cvisual;
int cdepth;

cvisual_template.screen = DefaultScreen(x_display);
cvisual_list = XGetVisualInfo(x_display, VisualScreenMask, &cvisual_template, &cnxvisuals);

/* The gstreamer video sink must play on a screen with 24-bit color. Otherwise it will fail */
XMatchVisualInfo(x_display, XDefaultScreen(x_display), 24, TrueColor, &cvinfo)

XSync(x_display, True);
cvisual = cvinfo.visual;
cdepth = cvinfo.depth;

XSetWindowAttributes  cswa;
cswa.event_mask = PointerMotionMask | KeyPressMask;
cswa.colormap = XCreateColormap(x_display, XDefaultRootWindow(x_display), cvisual, AllocNone);
cswa.background_pixel = 0;
cswa.border_pixel = 0;

/* Create the window */
gstreamer_window = XCreateWindow (
          x_display, main_window,
          0, 0, m_plane_width, m_plane_height, 0,
          cdepth, InputOutput,
          cvisual, CWEventMask | CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel,
          &cswa );

Window stack_position[2] = {opengl_window, gstreamer_window};
XRestackWindows(x_display, stack_position, 2);
```

Comment: You are putting both windows at the same location and with the same size. You will only be able to see the top one, since they are opaque.

Comment: My 32 bit window is a clear transparent window. When it runs I can see other windows underneath but not the other window that I set my parent to. Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: Two possibilities: your X server does not allow you to 'mix' 32 and 24 bit visuals like that (can you try a 32 bit visual for your gstream_window, if only temporary). Or, it will allow translucent windows to show contents of other clients (X11 programs), but not their own. The culprit in that case would be your window manager.

Comment: "My 32 bit window is a clear transparent window". Are you sure? X11 doesn't really support transparent windows out of the box. You need XCOMPOSITE and some elbow grease for it to work, or perhaps a special visual that supports transparency (not found everywhere). In most cases what looks like transparency is just background that the programmer failed to clear.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'd give an up vote to learn what your nickname / screen name means :)